# Yii2 : Upload Image using Kartik/FileInput Plugin

Tags: file-upload, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to upload an image via `Kartik` widget. After submitting the form, the `$_FILE['Product']` has the data about the image but `getInstance($model, 'images')` returns `null`. Tried with `images[]`, also null.
This is what I'm trying to `var_dump` in the controller:

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Product();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            var_dump(UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'images[]'));die;
```

And this is my model `Product`:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use backend\models\CActiveRecord;
use Yii;
use omgdef\multilingual\MultilingualQuery;
use omgdef\multilingual\MultilingualBehavior;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "product".
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property int $category_id
 * @property int $quantity
 * @property double $price
 * @property int $sort
 *
 * @property Productlang[] $productlangs
 */
class Product extends CActiveRecord
{
    public $images;

    public static function find()
    {
        return new MultilingualQuery(get_called_class());
    }

    public function behaviors()
    {
        $allLanguages = [];
        foreach (Yii::$app->params['languages'] as $title => $language) {
            $allLanguages[$title] = $language;
        }

        return [
            'ml' => [
                'class' => MultilingualBehavior::className(),
                'languages' => $allLanguages,
                //'languageField' => 'language',
                //'localizedPrefix' => '',
                //'requireTranslations' => false',
                //'dynamicLangClass' => true',
                //'langClassName' => PostLang::className(), // or namespace/for/a/class/PostLang
                'defaultLanguage' => Yii::$app->params['languageDefault'],
                'langForeignKey' => 'product_id',
                'tableName' => "{{%productLang}}",
                'attributes' => [
                    'title',
                    'description',
                    'meta_title',
                    'meta_desc',
                    'url'
                ]
            ],
        ];
    }
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'product';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        $string = $this->multilingualFields(['description', 'url']);
        $string_59 = $this->multilingualFields(['meta_title']);
        $string_255 = $this->multilingualFields(['meta_desc', 'title']);

        $string[] = 'description';
        $string[] = 'url';
        $string_59[] = 'meta_title';
        $string_255[] = 'meta_desc';
        $string_255[] = 'title';

        return [
            [['quantity', 'price', 'title', 'meta_title', 'meta_desc'], 'required'],
            [['category_id', 'quantity', 'sort'], 'integer'],
            [$string, 'string'],
            [$string_59, 'string', 'max' => 59],
            [$string_255, 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['price'], 'number'],
            ['images', 'file']
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'category_id' => 'Category ID',
            'quantity' => 'Quantity',
            'price' => 'Price',
            'sort' => 'Sort',
        ];
    }

    public function upload()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            foreach ($this->image as $file) {
                $file->saveAs(\Yii::getAlias("@images") . "/products/" . $this->id . "_" . $this->image->baseName . '.' . $this->image->extension);
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Tried with rules `['images', 'safe']` also `['images', 'file']` ( think the second one is not right because the attribute is an array, right ? ). The form is `<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['multipart/form-data']]); ?>`.
Finally my input:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'images[]')->widget(FileInput::class, [
                'showMessage' => true,
            ]) ?>
```

Full controller action:

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Product();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

            foreach (Yii::$app->params['languages'] as $language){
                if(Yii::$app->params['languageDefault'] != $language){

                    $title_lang = "title_$language";
                    $model->$title_lang = Yii::$app->request->post('Product')["title_$language"];

                    $description_lang = "description_$language";
                    $model->$description_lang = Yii::$app->request->post('Product')["description_$language"];

                    $meta_title_lang = "meta_title_$language";
                    $model->$meta_title_lang = Yii::$app->request->post('Product')["meta_title_$language"];

                    $meta_desc_lang = "meta_desc_$language";
                    $model->$meta_desc_lang = Yii::$app->request->post('Product')["meta_desc_$language"];

                }
            }

            if($model->save()){

                $model = $this->findModel($model->id, true);

                //Make urls
                foreach (Yii::$app->params['languages'] as $language) {
                    if (Yii::$app->params['languageDefault'] != $language) {
                        $url_lang = "url_$language";
                        $title_lang = "title_$language";
                        $model->$url_lang = $model->constructURL(
                            $model->$title_lang,
                            $model->id
                        );
                    }else{
                        $model->url = $model->constructURL(
                            $model->title,
                            $model->id
                        );
                    }
                }

                //Upload Images
                $model->images = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'images');
                if (!($model->upload())) {
                    Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error',  Yii::t('app', 'Some problem with the image uploading occure!'));
                    return $this->redirect(['create']);
                }


                if($model->update() !== false){
                    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
                }else{
                    Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error',  Yii::t('app', 'Something went wrong. Please, try again later!'));
                    return $this->redirect(['create']);
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: why are you saving images twice inside your action?

Comment: Where ? This `if($model->save())` part ? This don't save the image I think. On the save method I didn't save it because I don't invoke the `upload()` method, right ?

Comment: `//Save image
                $model->images = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'images');
                if(!empty($model->images)){
                    $model->upload();
                }` right after `$model->save()` and  then `//Upload Images
                $model->images = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'images');
                if (!($model->upload())) {
                    Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error',  Yii::t('app', 'Some problem with the image uploading occure!'));
                    return $this->redirect(['create']);
                }` after `//Make urls`

Comment: My bad ... the first is unnecessary.

Comment: you are calling `if($model->save())` first and then inside the check you are again overriding the `$model->url` OR `$model->$url_lang` and then again calling `$model->update()` ?

Comment: Yes, because I need the id of the model to create the `$model->url`. That's why I first save it and after that, finding it again by `$this->findModel .... `.

Comment: hmm , ok , the files you are trying to upload are mandatory or optional ? i am trying to give it a go and will update my answer need a few questions to ask

Comment: They are optional. You can make a model without image/s.

Comment: see below i edited my answer see the edit section and replace the sections as described.

Answer (score 0):

What looks like you are trying to upload a single image you should remove the `[]` from the input field name from the ActiveForm field declaration, and from models rules.

### `Single File`

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'images')->widget(FileInput::class, [
                'showMessage' => true,
                'pluginOptions' => [
                        'showCaption' => false ,
                        'showRemove' => false ,
                        'showUpload' => false ,
                        'showPreview' => false ,
                        'browseClass' => 'btn btn-success btn-block' ,
                        'browseIcon' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></i> ' ,
                        'browseLabel' => 'Select Profile Image'
                    ] ,
                    'options' => ['accept' => 'image/*' ] ,
            ]) ?>
```

and from the following line

```
UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'images');
```

### `Multiple Files`

For multiple files you need to add `'options' => ['multiple' => true]` for the field and change the attribute name to `images[]`

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'images[]')->widget(FileInput::class, [
                'showMessage' => true,
                'pluginOptions' => [
                        'showCaption' => false ,
                        'showRemove' => false ,
                        'showUpload' => false ,
                        'showPreview' => false ,
                        'browseClass' => 'btn btn-success btn-block' ,
                        'browseIcon' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></i> ' ,
                        'browseLabel' => 'Select Profile Image'
                    ] ,
                    'options' => ['accept' => 'image/*' ,'multiple'=>true] ,
            ]) ?>
```

and for receiving the uploaded files you should not specify the attribute as an array just change `getInstance` to `getInstances` and then try printing, it will show you all the images use `foreach()` to save all of them.

```
UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'images');
```

I personally prefer to use a separate model for file uploading rather than using the ActiveRecord model.

*Note: When using multiple files upload, you can also specify the `'maxFiles'=>1000` inside you model rules to limit the number of files to be uploaded*

**EDIT**

For troubleshooting your code you should comment out the `actionCreate` from the controller and replace with the one i added below

```
public function actionCreate() {
    $model = new Product();

    if ( $model->load ( Yii::$app->request->post () ) ) {

        foreach ( Yii::$app->params['languages'] as $language ) {
            if ( Yii::$app->params['languageDefault'] != $language ) {

                $title_lang = "title_$language";
                $model->$title_lang = Yii::$app->request->post ( 'Product' )["title_$language"];

                $description_lang = "description_$language";
                $model->$description_lang = Yii::$app->request->post ( 'Product' )["description_$language"];

                $meta_title_lang = "meta_title_$language";
                $model->$meta_title_lang = Yii::$app->request->post ( 'Product' )["meta_title_$language"];

                $meta_desc_lang = "meta_desc_$language";
                $model->$meta_desc_lang = Yii::$app->request->post ( 'Product' )["meta_desc_$language"];
            }
        }

        $transaction = Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction ();

        try {
            if ( !$model->save () ) {
                throw new \Exception ( implode ( "<br />" , \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::getColumn ( $model->errors , 0 , false ) ) );
            }

            //Make urls
            foreach ( Yii::$app->params['languages'] as $language ) {
                if ( Yii::$app->params['languageDefault'] != $language ) {
                    $url_lang = "url_$language";
                    $title_lang = "title_$language";
                    $model->$url_lang = $model->constructURL (
                            $model->$title_lang , $model->id
                    );
                } else {
                    $model->url = $model->constructURL (
                            $model->title , $model->id
                    );
                }
            }

            //save the new urls
            if ( !$model->save () ) {
                throw new \Exception ( implode ( "<br />" , \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::getColumn ( $model->errors , 0 , false ) ) );
            }

            //Upload Images
            $model->images = UploadedFile::getInstances ( $model , 'images' );
            $model->upload ();

            //commit the transatction to save the record in the table
            $transaction->commit ();

            Yii::$app->session->setFlash ( 'success' , 'The model saved successfully.' );
            return $this->redirect ( [ 'view' , 'id' => $model->id ] );
        } catch ( \Exception $ex ) {
            $transaction->rollBack ();
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash ( 'error' , Yii::t ( 'app' , $ex->getMessage () ) );
        }
    }

    return $this->render ( 'create' , [
                'model' => $model ,
            ] );
}
```

And comment out the `upload()` function of your model and add below function

```
public function upload() {
    $skipped = [];
    foreach ( $this->images as $file ) {
        if ( !$file->saveAs ( \Yii::getAlias ( "@images" ) . "/products/" . $this->id . "_" . $this->image->baseName . '.' . $this->image->extension ) ) {
            $skipped[] = "File " . $file->baseName . " was not saved.";
        }
    }
    if ( !empty ( $skipped ) ) {
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash ( 'error' , implode ( "<br>" , $skipped ) );
    }
}
```

And for the ActiveForm make sure your input matches the following

```
$form->field($model, 'images[]')->widget(FileInput::class, [
            'showMessage' => true,
            'pluginOptions' => [
                    'showCaption' => false ,
                    'showRemove' => false ,
                    'showUpload' => false ,
                    'showPreview' => false ,
                    'browseClass' => 'btn btn-success btn-block' ,
                    'browseIcon' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></i> ' ,
                    'browseLabel' => 'Select Profile Image'
                ] ,
                'options' => ['accept' => 'image/*','multiple'=>true ] ,
]) ;
```

Comment: Yes, it works with single image. But when I try with multiple it doesnt upload them . `getInstance` returns null ( then I am using the brackets :) ).  I have table for them - `product_image` and respectively a model `ProductImage`. Guess after the whole tests I forgot to fix the `images` property. But after the fix it doesnt work with multiple again. Returns null.

Comment: Still `NULL`. I am really confused because I don't doing this for first time .. Model propery `public $images = [];` ; Form field `<?= $form->field($model, 'images[]')->widget(FileInput::class, [ 'options' => ['multiple' => true]) ?>` ; controller `UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'images')`. Also tried with your `$form->field` above just for case. Can it be something with Yii2 version ? Mine is `2.0.14` and the one that I am working at work is Yii2 `2.0.6` :/

Comment: it should be `UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'images')` rather than `getInstance` if that's not a typo writing here, i am currently testing it on `2.0.15.1`, its strange that you are getting `NULL`, can you add complete code for the action, and don't declare the property as an array, just declare it like `public $images` @TomaTomov

Comment: cant you update the framework by running composer update, i tested these settings on my local machine and they are working correctly

Comment: Mine is updated to `2.0.14` and the setups don't work. On the older version `2.0.6` it works. I don't think this is the case but it is something that I notice. Guess there is something in my code... will keep trying and will post if something happens. Will update to `2.0.15`

Comment: i just noticed you have an `upload` function and you are trying to iterate on the `foreach ($this->image as $file) {` whereas your attribute defined is `images` @TomaTomov , can you add the complete controller/action you have.

Comment: Yes. It is above.